# getComputedStyle not being updated when updating style for test

Tags: javascript, css, dom

I want to create a mock div that has display: none for testing purposes. However, setting the display in the test and then calling getComputedStyle shows no change in the style, i.e.

```js
const parent = document.createElement('div');
const middle = document.createElement('div');

// If you check in the dom, the middle div clearly has display: none as 
// part of its style
middle.style.display = 'none';
parent.appendChild(middle);

// Supposed to be 'none', but is actually ''
console.log(getComputedStyle(middle).display);
```

It seems like other people have said that getComputedStyle forces a redraw of the screen, but it seems like it is not getting the updated display of middle. How can I force getComputedStyle to update to the display value?

Comment: You need to actually insert the node in the document for `getComputedStyle` to return `none` https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/g2x3zt0d/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getComputedStyle` returns empty string for the `display` property unless the node is added to the `DOM`. You can see that also the initial computed style value is empty, because the node was not added to the DOM.

As mentioned [in the spec](https://drafts.csswg.org/cssom/#dom-window-getcomputedstyle), at step 5, the element has to be connected:

> If elt is connected, part of the flat tree, and its shadow-including root has a browsing context which either doesn’t have a browsing context container, or whose browsing context container is being rendered, set decls to a list of all longhand properties that are supported CSS properties, in lexicographical order, with the value being the resolved value computed for obj using the style rules associated with doc.

```js
const parent = document.createElement('div');
const middle = document.createElement('div');

console.log('Initial style: ', getComputedStyle(middle).display);
// If you check in the dom, the middle div clearly has display: none as 
// part of its style
middle.style.display = 'none';
parent.appendChild(middle);

// Adding this, now it shows the correct value
document.body.appendChild(parent);

// Supposed to be 'none', but is actually ''
console.log('Display: ', getComputedStyle(middle).display);
```

Comment: Based on the specs I still find it a bit confusing that `getComputedStyle` returns the list of all CSS properties with the value of empty string. One possible answer would be that by default `getComputedStyle` creates the same empty list of CSSDeclarations as the default `style` object of an `HTMLElement`, and then it actually overwrites those empty strings with the actual styles of the element.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `parent` element to the DOM using `document.body.appendChild(parent)`. If an element is not in the DOM, it doesn't have any computed styles.

```js
const parent = document.createElement('div');
const middle = document.createElement('div');

// If you check in the dom, the middle div clearly has display: none as 
// part of its style
middle.style.display = 'none';
parent.appendChild(middle);
document.body.appendChild(parent);

// Supposed to be 'none', but is actually ''
console.log(getComputedStyle(middle).display);
```